# Indentation of a longtable

Tags: indentation, longtable

I have a table without borders, spanning two pages, the text contained in which I want to start with the same indentation as my hanging footnotes. I have a rough solution, but it relies on inserting an empty column at the left and guessing its necessary width. I thought the width of the first column should be `\leftmargin`, as for the hanging indent of the footnotes, but obviously there are some `tabcolsep`s and possibly other things I am yet unaware of. `0.35\leftmargin` seems a lot less than what I'd expect. What would be a safe formula, possibly using the `calc` package for calculating the necessary space as argument to `p` in the table declaration, or is there a more straightforward way of getting the same output?

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\footmarkwidth}{\leftmargin}
\setlength{\footmarksep}{0em}
\footmarkstyle{#1\hfill}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\begin{longtable}[l]{p{0.35\leftmargin}ll}
& Chapters & Description\\
& 1--13 & Something \\
& 14 & Something else\\
\end{longtable}

\noindent Here some text.\footnote{\lipsum[1]}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `@` operator for setting the margin:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\footmarkwidth}{\leftmargin}
\setlength{\footmarksep}{0em}
\footmarkstyle{#1\hfill}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-4]

    \begin{longtable}[l]{ @{\hspace*{\leftmargin}} ll}
        Chapters & Description\\
        1--13 & Something \\
        14 & Something else\\
    \end{longtable}

    \noindent Here some text.\footnote{\lipsum[1]}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Where do I find a good explanation of the `@` operator?

Comment: run `texdoc array`

Comment: What do I do if the contents of the right column is longer, so that a line break will be needed? I guess I then have to change the last column from `l` to `p{}` to specify a fixed length, but how do I calculate that?

Comment: Use package `ltablex` and then the column specifier `X`. Instead of `longtable` you have to use `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{...}`. Then it does the calculation for you. I