# Nomenclature with nomentbl - remove indent

Tags: indentation, nomenclature

Is there a way to remove the indent in the nomenclature. I want the headings (e.g. "Latin Letters") to flush left.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,
               paper=a4,
               british,
              ]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{nomentbl}
\makenomenclature


\begin{document} 
\nomenclature[Ax]{$x$}{Coordinate}{-}%

\printnomenclature

\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the nomenclature style file for Makeindex to force the table to the margin by using `\hspace*{0pt}` (as in [Indentation of a longtable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/252938/indentation-of-a-longtable)). Use the following style file, and save it as, e.g., `mynomentbl.ist` in the same folder as your `.tex` file:

```
actual '@'
quote '%'
delim_0   ""
delim_1   ""
delim_2   ""
item_0    ""
delim_t   " \\\\\n"
line_max  1000
heading_prefix   "\\multicolumn{3}{@{\\hspace*{0pt}}l}{\\nomgroup{"
heading_suffix   "}} \\\\\n\\nopagebreak\\\\*[\\parskip]\n\\nopagebreak{}"
headings_flag       1
group_skip        "\\\\*[\\parskip]"
preamble "\n\\begin{thenomenclature}\n%
\\begin{longtable}[l]%
{@{\\hspace*{0pt}}cp{\\textwidth*\\real{0.5}}c!{\\extracolsep{\\fill}}lll}\n"
postamble "\n\\end{longtable}\n\n\\end{thenomenclature}\n"
keyword "\\nomenclatureentry"

%%
%%


\endinput
```

Then compile the nomenclature using the new index style file:

```
makeindex -s mynomentbl.ist -o yourfile.nls yourfile.nlo
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works, but it seems that the now left aligned lines are a bit too far left compared to the heading "Nomenclature". Is there a way to fix this or why is the distance to the margin different?

Comment: @user195973 Larger fonts usually show a bit more space around the letters, so it is normal that the N is a bit further out than the nomenclature entries itself. Compare the _xyz_ in my screenshot, in the code this is `\noindent xyz` (outside of the table), so that is the position of normal, non-indented text. But if you want to shift the lines you can just change the `0pt` value (in two places, in the `heading_prefix` line and after `\\begin{longtable}`) to something else, positive (1pt, 2pt, etc) to shift right, and negative (-1pt, -2pt, etc) to shift left.